# How to use sendTransaction to send ERC20 tokens through Metamask?

Tags: web3js, erc-20, metamask

I have a custom ERC20 token and I want to enable metamask support. By this I mean:

1) The user clicks a "Pay using metamask" button

2) The Metamask payment window pops up and with "Pay 100 ABC tokens" (not ETH), with the usual gas price, etc.

How would I do this? I wrote my method halfway, but realized it would only work for ETH.

My ethereum.js file:

```
const sendTransaction = ({ cost, to, gasPrice }) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const ethereum = window.ethereum;
      const Web3 = window.Web3;
      const web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
      try {
        ethereum.enable().then(accounts => {
          const from = accounts[0];
          web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {
              from,
              to,
              gasPrice,
              value: "1000000000000000000"
            },
            (err, res) => {
              err ? reject(err) : resolve();
            }
          );
        });
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    } else if (window.web3) {
      const Web3 = window.Web3;
      const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
      web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
        const from = accounts[0];

        web3.eth.sendTransaction(
          {
            to,
            from,
            value: "1000000000000000000"
          },
          (err, res) => {
            err ? reject(err) : resolve();
          }
        );
      });
    } else {
      console.log(
        "Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!"
      );
    }
  });

export default {
  sendTransaction
};
```

Comment: You need to create instance of your token contract and call the transfer function with appropriate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donot use `value` field if you dont want to send `ether`. `Value` field is only used for `ether`. Now you have to construct the `data` for the transaction. if using `web3@0.2.0` then you can do

```
contractData = contractInstance.transfer.getData(address, amount)
//contractData = '0x12345643213456000000000023434234'
```

this will give you the data for the transaction. After that the `transaction object` will look like this

```
{
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
    data: contractData,
    to: contractAddress,
    chainId: 1(main net), 2(expanse), 4(rinkeby)
    from: fromAddress
}
```

But it wont say `"Pay 100 ABC tokens"`, but there will be a popup for confirmation to send `transaction`

Comment: do you know what i would need to change for web3 @ 1.0?

Comment: also, where do i get the nonce?

Comment: `npm uninstall <name> --save` to remove the previous `web3js` and then `npm install web3js --save` to install the latest version. For the nonce use `web3.eth.getTransactionCount("address").then(console.log);` web3js@1.0.0